# Filter and Sum Visible Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel file has several rows associated with the same country.

I need to filter by country ISO code, then sum the quarterly data of 2015 to create a new column with the sum, but a sum only with visible cells.
Then repeat this for the following years (2016, 2017, etc.).
Then sum row totals (e.g. of 2015) and copy the sum to a different cell in a different worksheet of the same file.

Below you can find my attempt. I run two separate macros:

MACRO1

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim LR As Long

Sheets("WEBSTATS_DEBTSEC_DATAFLOW_csv_c").Select
Sheets("WEBSTATS_DEBTSEC_DATAFLOW_csv_c").Range("$A$1:$BF$218591").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="SA"
    
LR = Range("AJ" & Rows.Count).End(.xlUp).Row
Range("AJ2" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

End sub
```

MACRO2

```vb
Sub Macro2()

    Sheets("Country Total").Select
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(WEBSTATS_DEBTSEC_DATAFLOW_csv_c!R[346]C[36]:R[174666]C[36])"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to filter and then sum only visible items? Will the standard function Sumifs() not work to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to use filter function in this case. In fact even VBA is not necessary. You can just use Excel's SUMIF (https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) function for this particular case.

If you would like to keep using Excel's Filter Function (for example if you want to be able to add more criterias later on) the excel function SUBTOTAL (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function can be used to only apply an operation (i.e. sum) on the "visible" (= filtered) rows